# Inrush current calculation in capacitive circuite.............?

Tags: capacitor, inrush-current

I am using the following circuit to make a transformer-less AC to DC converter.
It is working fine in my case. Now I need to protect my rectifying diodes from damage due to inrush current in this circuit.Here the resistor R4 is used to limit the inrush current.So to select a suitable value for R4 I need to calculate the maximum inrush current current in this circuit.
So how can I calculate the inrush current in this circuit........? What about the surge power in R4?
What will be the suitable value for R4....?[image]

Comment: Inrush current will be roughly \$2\pi\cdot f\cdot V_{AC p-p}\cdot C_2\$. But normal peak currents will be roughly \$1.5\cdot V_{ripple} / t_{charge}\cdot C_2\$ and you want those to pass without significant drop. You have to make a judgment here if you will just use a resistor, \$R_4\$. But \$R_1\$ and \$C_1\$ are a different story and I'd like to hear your purpose there. \$C_1\$ certainly complicates the inrush current calcs, for example.

Comment: What is your estimated load current? I can see the zener and the LED... but what about the rest?

Comment: Worst-case inrush current for a transformerless supply will be when it is connected to the source at maximum peak voltage with all of its capacitors discharged. So in this case, treat the capacitors as short-circuits (so ignore R1 and everything to the right of C2) and calculate R4 with simple R=Vpk/Imax where Vpk is your peak AC line voltage and Imax is the maximum current you want your rectifiers to have to withstand.

Comment: You do know that 1N4007s will be happy with 30A for a half-cycle?

Comment: @iqbalpalemad  This offline cap charge supply must only be used for constant load apps. not relays to bulbs controlled by Uno. then use NTC with R4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you assume that AC is 240V,RMS and can be turned ON instantaneously at any angle, that C2 is completely discharged before AC power-up, and that the the voltage drop across each of the diodes in the bridge is 1 volt, then if the mains  are enerizgized  at at either  \$90 ^{\circ}\$ degrees or \$270^{\circ}\$  the instantaneous initial current out of the mains, on power-up  will be:

$$ I = \frac{340V - 2V}{100\Omega} = 3.38 amperes $$

Answer (score 1):

Either of these will work up to 47uF @240Vac while you are using 2.2uF with a temp rise of 90'C/W being regulated at the Curie Temp with free air.

[image]